# XCode iOS 1 TableView for iPhone and iPad?

Tags: tableview, cell

I have a `UITableView` with a custom cell and they are both for the iPad(size)
What is the best way to go? Should I create a new `UITableView` nib and a new Cell nib and call them or just resize them when needed?
Please also give me instructions how to either of these solutions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

table views aren't generally used on their own on ipads due to them having a lot more space, generally the design pattern is to have a small table view along the left and a content area on the right. I believe there is a uisplitviewcontroller to handle this.

Comment: I took the tableview and made it unscrollable and set the height of the cells to 96 which fills the view. And the view is not a whole page, because I'm calling the view like this: navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

Comment: That works fine for the iPad, but for the iPhone I wanna call it normally, but do I need a new TableView and a new Cell or should I just resize the existing ones?

Comment: I'd create new ones if there going to have different behaviour / settings. will just be easier

Comment: Should I create new nibs and hook them up with the existing classes from the iPad or should I create nibs + new classes and code just the same?

Comment: I would say new nibs and keep the same classes so long as there won't be a lot of if iphone do this, if ipad do this

Answer (score 1):

I created a new Cell nib only for the iPhone and in the VC of the tableview I checked if the app is running on an iPhone or iPad and called the right nib.

```
    NSArray *objects;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
    objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell-iPad" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    else {
    objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell-iPhone" owner:self options:nil];
    }
```